# Reset Date or DateTime data item in Blue Prism

Tags: datetime, reset, blueprism, rpa

I am reading a queue and using an Action stage to "Get Item Data" from "Work Queue" business object. The purpose of my process to prepare a report of the status of the queue items. The "Get Item Data" action expects one input, which is the queue item ID. A bunch of output items are spit out such as Key, Status, Completed DateTime, Exception DateTime...etc.

I generated Data Items for all of the output of the "Get Item Data" Action stage. I then created a loop to go over all the queue records, populate the generated data items, and then use the information in the data items to captured the details for my reporting.

The issue that I am having is that when the loop goes to the next item in the queue, it does not entirely reset the data items. For example, if the first record in the queue was in completed status, the "Completed DateTime" data item is populated with that date and time. If the next record in the queue is an exception, it populates the "Exception DateTime" data item, which is good, but it doesn't override the "Complete DateTime" data item with blank. It keeps the date from the previous record.

In my process, I check for "Completed DateTime" and "Exception DateTime" in order to determine the status of the record and update my report. The solution that I thought of is to add a Calculation stage to reset the data items, but can't seem to reset a DateTime data item. It does not like the empty quotes "". Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

FYI, one of the output items is called "Status", but it is not populated with any information. Otherwise, this would have been very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This may not be the ideal solution, but it'll work!

Use the Calculation Stage at the end of the loop, but as you cannot set a DateTime object to 'empty', how about you set them to an *odd* date? E.g. `01-01-4000 00:00:00`.

After you finish your initial loop to populate the report (I assume something similar to Excel), you create another loop over your report and replace all the *odd* dates to empty cells. Alternatively you write a macro to get rid of them all at once without the need to loop.

The best solution of course would be to properly populate the `Status` column in your queue, but this requires access to the code and permission to alter it (and time to do so).

Comment: This is the correct answer. As you’ve determined, the DateTime data items in this process do not necessarily correspond to a record that has been successfully or unsuccessfully processed. You should be using other, more definite means to determine if a case was processed successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I will check other data items that can give more definite state of the case, but if the DateTime is my only option, using an odd date is a good idea. Thanks again!